# In Julia NFFT, replace vector and matrix methods with a single array method

Tags: multidimensional-array, metaprogramming, julia

In the NFFT package there are fast, specialized functions for vectors and matrices and slow functions for general arrays. I would like to make the general function fast and the specialized functions obsolete, but I'm running into trouble.

One family of specialized functions look essentially like this (`offset` is computed in the actual code, but its *value* is not important for this question):

```
myfunc!(f::Vector, g::Vector)
    offset = 5
    n = length(g)
    N = length(f)

    for l = 1:N
        g[ ((l+offset)%n)+1 ] = f[l]
    end
end
```

and

```
myfunc!(f::Matrix, g::Matrix)
    offsetx = 5
    offsety = 5
    n1, n2 = size(g)
    N1, N2 = size(f)

    for ly = 1:N2
        for lx = 1:N1
            g[ ((lx+offsetx)%n1)+1, ((ly+offsety)%n2)+1 ] = f[lx, ly]
        end
    end
end
```

The general function could be written like this

```
myfunc!{D}(f::Array{D}, g::Array{D})
    offset = ntuple(d -> 5, D)
    n = size(g)

    for l in CartesianRange(size(f))
        idx = CartesianIndex{D}( ntuple(d -> ((l[d]+offset[d])%n[d])+1, D) )
        g[ idx ] = f[l]
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, this is terribly slow. The majority of the time is spent in the `ntuple` in the loop.

Other possibilities for `idx` include letting `idx = Array{Int}(D)` and make the inner loop look like

```
for d = 1:D
    idx[d] = ((l[d]+offset[d])%n[d])+1
end
g[idx...] = f[l]
```

This is also slow.

I'm thinking that since the dimension `D` is a type argument, a `@generated` function can be made for computing `idx`, but I cannot figure out how to do that (or if there is a better way).

I'm using Julia v0.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for how to do this with a generated function is
to use the [Base.Cartesian](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/devdocs/cartesian/) helper macros.

```
using Base.Cartesian 

@generated function myfunc!{T,D}(f::Array{T,D}, g::Array{T,D})
    quote
        @nexprs $D d->offset_d=5 #Declase offset_1=5, offset_2=5 etc

        @nloops $D l f begin
            (@nref $D g d->(l_d+offset_d)%size(g,d)+1) = @nref $D f l 
        end
    end
end
```

I have confirmed this is correct, for 2D at least.
I leave it as an excise to the reader to profile it.
It more or less does not allocate.

Comment: Very nice solution! With this approach I oversimplified the OP. I also have a third input `h::Vector{Vector{Float64}}` and (in the 2D case) the inner loop changes from
`g[((lx+offsetx)%n1)+1, ((ly+offsety)%n2)+1] = f[lx, ly]`
to
`g[((lx+offsetx)%n1)+1, ((ly+offsety)%n2)+1] = f[lx, ly] * h[1][lx] * h[2][ly]`.
Can these terms also be included using `Base.Cartesian`. It seems like nested `@nref`'s are a no-go.

Comment: Sure: Change the inner most section (the `@nref`) to:
`v = @nref $D f l`; 
`@nexprs $D d-> v*=h[d][l_d]`; 
`(@nref $D g d->(l_d+offset_d)%size(g,d)+1) = v`;